# How to stop remote service

Tags: android, service, process

I have created a service and an activity. In that activity I have two buttons. One is to start service and another to stop service. I can start the remote activity by calling `startService()` but unable to stopr service using `stopService()`. If i click on start button I found extra remote process strarted  running (using eclipse ide). I am expecting if i click on stop button then that additional process shouls stop. but Its not happening. I am able to call start and stop service method successfully. To verify the code I have added a toast message in each start and stop method.  How to stop remote service?

### My Activity

```
public class SimpleServiceController extends Activity {

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.serviceButton);
            Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

            start.setOnClickListener(startListener);
            stop.setOnClickListener(stopListener);

       }

       private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            startService(new Intent(SimpleServiceController.this,SimpleService.class));
        }               
       };

       private OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                stopService(new Intent(SimpleServiceController.this,SimpleService.class));
            }               
          };
}
```

### Service

```
public class SimpleService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

### Manifest

```
<service android:name=".SimpleService" android:process=":remote">
        </service>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Android, there's an important distinction between a running **service** and a running **process**.

A **service** follows a [carefully defined lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle); it begins when `onStartCommand()` is called and ends after `onDestroy()` is finished.  During that lifetime, the service can be performing tasks or sitting idle, but it is still running.

A **process** can extend beyond the life of a service. As you've seen, the process can keep running for some time after your service has stopped.  **Don't worry about it**.  Android will destroy the process and reclaim any resources exactly when it needs to. It's definitely confusing at first, but once your service has stopped, you don't need to care about the process it was in.

**Bottom line:** if `onDestroy` has been called, your service has stopped. Don't worry about the leftover process.